# Firebase Client JS SDK - Where to save private keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

Until now, I was saving my Firebase project private keys in the app.json of my React Native app.  Like this:

```
"web": {
  "config": {
    "firebase": {
      "apiKey": "x",
      "authDomain": "x.firebaseapp.com",
      "databaseUrl": "https://x.firebaseio.com",
      "projectId": "x",
      "storageBucket": "x.appspot.com",
      "messagingSenderId": "x",
      ...
    }
  }
},
```

But looking at the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), I have seen the following:

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your
> React app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

So, if I shouldn't store secrets in the front-end, how do I use the Firebase client sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API key from the config is not a secret key, it's a [public key](https://rapidapi.com/blog/api-glossary/api-key) which is used as an identifier and part of the encryption process  - so it doesn't need to be protected.

If you would create a new or use an existing [service account](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/service-accounts) with potentially critical access to the backend infrastructure, the private key from that account should never be included in your frontend code.

Instead, you would create i.e. a [firebase cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) where you can use the secret without exposing it to the outside world.